# How can I add a range of values to my database via SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I need to be able to send a range of Date values to my database. Here is my current working solution for adding a single date at a time:

HTML:
EDIT: I updated the HTML form to include the from/to fields instead of a single field.

```
<form method="post" action="/PHP/update.php">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">From:</td>
<td><input name="fromdate" type="date" id="fromdate"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">To:</td>
<td><input name="todate" type="date" id="todate"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Customer Name</td>
<td><input name="name" type="text" id="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

header( "refresh:2;url=/protected/update.html" );

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'USER';
$dbpass = 'PASS';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$date = $_POST['date'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO calendar (date, customer)
VALUES ('$date', '$name')";

mysqli_select_db($conn, 'website_main');
$retval = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
echo "Updated data successfully,\n";
echo "You will be re-directed shortly.\n";
mysqli_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<?php
}
?>
```

This setup currently allows me to send a single date per click of the update button in the html form.

However I would like to edit the form ( which I can do myself ) to have Dates: From [dd/mm/yyyy] to [dd/mm/yyy]. and then when I hit update, the PHP would be able to fill in the blanks e.g. if it were 01/01/2016 to 03/01/2016, the PHP would submit to the database 01/01/2016, 02/01/2016 and 03/01/2016.

I am a total PHP noob, and had a lot of issues even trying to get the single date submission working. Any and all help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I should have clarified this to begin with, my apologies. The Database is linked up to a calendar which updates and marks the dates red which are in the database. Because of this, each date MUST have an individual entry in the table. I CANNOT have startDate and endDate as 2 seperate columns in the same entry, due to the way that I have already setup the calendar. Is there any way around this without having to redo the code for my calendar?

Comment: I will try to clarify my opinion, so I deleted my previous comment. If you want to submit three dates  to the database, you should have three different fields. Supposing that you don't have EXACTLY the same range for each update you want to do (for example 3 days), this is impossible, in my opinion. So it's better to keep two different `DATE` fields in your DB and store the beginning and the end.



As for the PHP part, you could just have a `for` loop traversing from the beginning date to the end date and building a query, but as I already said, I don't think that this is convenient.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would have preferred using just two  dates start_date and end_date and compare every date while retrieving data. Well according to your requirement you can use this code and save comma separated dates.

```
  while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
     echo "$date\n";
     $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
 }
```

However the former one will be the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should catch both date parameters and save it in the database.
You can do it with:

```
$todate = $_POST['fromdate'];
$fromdate = $_POST['todate'];
```

Then you need to add a new column in your table. The new SQL can look like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO calendar (fromdate,todate, customer)
VALUES ('".$fromdate."', '".$todate."', '".$name."')";
```

With the columns fromdate, todate and customer.
If you want to fill in the blank fields you should make a PHP file for the form. Then you have a method to hand over the attributes. Like sending it via GET.

```
header( "refresh:2;url=/protected/update.php" );

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'USER';
$dbpass = 'PASS';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$todate = $_POST['fromdate'];
$fromdate = $_POST['todate'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO calendar (fromdate,todate, customer)
VALUES ('".$fromdate."', '".$todate."', '".$name."')";

mysqli_select_db($conn, 'website_main');
$retval = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
echo "Updated data successfully,\n";
echo "You will be re-directed shortly.\n";
mysqli_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Huge thanks to Harish Lalwani for pointing me down the right line for this.

A slight adaption to his suggestion worked a treat and I have managed to create a while loop which increments the date each loop until it reaches the end date.

The working PHP:

```
<?php

header( "refresh:2;url=/protected/update.html" );

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'aidan';
$dbpass = 'Bathgate69107965';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$fromDate = $_POST['fromdate'];
$toDate = $_POST['todate'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

$date = $fromDate;

  while ($date <= $toDate) {

$sql = "INSERT INTO calendar (date, customer)
VALUES ('$date', '$name')";

mysqli_select_db($conn, 'website_main');
$retval = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
echo "Updated data successfully,\n";

$date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));

}
echo "You will be re-directed shortly.\n";
mysqli_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<?php
}
?>
```